# How can I find the Harddisk Device Serial Number without using the WMI in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wmi, hard-drive

I want to get the hardwired serial number from the hard disk but NOT using WMI. I tried using WMI code, and it doesn't work on my machine for sure. So is there any alternative in .NET for finding the Serial Number of a physical hard disk?

Comment: Open up the box and have a look?

Comment: This has been asked so often ...

Comment: No this one is difference..........he need serial no of hard drive  not the serial no each volume of the hard drive

Comment: i also looking for answer because i am facing same problem.......

Answer (score 4):

This should help get started:

[How to get Physical HDD serial number without WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/DriveInfoEx.aspx)

Regarding your problem with WMI not returning data; Are you sure how to the right privileges to get data from WMI? You can use [WMI Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6430F853-1120-48DB-8CC5-F2ABDC3ED314&displaylang=en) to check/fix this.

Comment: I am running the code in the limited account mode. So I guess thats the problem. IS there any way I can elevate my privileges from within the limited account?

Comment: I don't think so. Wouldn't that miss the whole point of assigning privileges to users? Or if you know the admin-password, you can use the "runas" command.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [createfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) as shown below. It may require administrative permissions.Add 4 text boxes and a button in your code.

```
 private const int CREATE_NEW = 1;
    private const int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    private const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000; 
    private const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
    // 10000000000000000000000000000000 --- GENERIC_READ
    // 01000000000000000000000000000000 --- GENERIC_WRITE
    // 00100000000000000000000000000000 --- GENERIC_EXECUTE
    // 00010000000000000000000000000000 --- GENERIC_ALL       

    //Securable objects use an access mask format in which the 
    //four high-order bits specify generic access rights


    private const int FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x1;      
    private const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x2;
    // 00000000000000000000000000000001 --- FILE_SHARE_READ
    // 00000000000000000000000000000010 --- FILE_SHARE_WRITE
    // 00000000000000000000000000000100 --- FILE_SHARE_DELETE 

    private const int VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT = 2;
    private const int DFP_RECEIVE_DRIVE_DATA = 0x7C088;
    //     0         000000000000111         11                  0               00000100010         00
    //     Common    Device Type             Required Access     Custom          Function Code       Transfer Type

    private const int INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

    public enum DriveTypes { Fixed, Removable, Unknown };
    public string[] DriveStrings = { "Fixed", "Removable", "Unknown" };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 8)]
    private class IDEREGS
    {
        public byte Features;
        public byte SectorCount;
        public byte SectorNumber;
        public byte CylinderLow;
        public byte CylinderHigh;
        public byte DriveHead;
        public byte Command;
        public byte Reserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 32)]
    private class SENDCMDINPARAMS
    {
        public int BufferSize;
        public IDEREGS DriveRegs;
        public byte DriveNumber;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public byte[] Reserved;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
        public int[] Reserved2;
        public SENDCMDINPARAMS()
        {
            DriveRegs = new IDEREGS();
            Reserved = new byte[3];
            Reserved2 = new int[4];
        }
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 12)]
    private class DRIVERSTATUS
    {
        public byte DriveError;
        public byte IDEStatus;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public byte[] Reserved;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public int[] Reserved2;
        public DRIVERSTATUS()
        {
            Reserved = new byte[2];
            Reserved2 = new int[2];
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class IDSECTOR
    {
        public short GenConfig;
        public short NumberCylinders;
        public short Reserved;
        public short NumberHeads;
        public short BytesPerTrack;
        public short BytesPerSector;
        public short SectorsPerTrack;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public short[] VendorUnique;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
        public char[] SerialNumber;
        public short BufferClass;
        public short BufferSize;
        public short ECCSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public char[] FirmwareRevision;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 40)]
        public char[] ModelNumber;
        public short MoreVendorUnique;
        public short DoubleWordIO;
        public short Capabilities;
        public short Reserved1;
        public short PIOTiming;
        public short DMATiming;
        public short BS;
        public short NumberCurrentCyls;
        public short NumberCurrentHeads;
        public short NumberCurrentSectorsPerTrack;
        public int CurrentSectorCapacity;
        public short MultipleSectorCapacity;
        public short MultipleSectorStuff;
        public int TotalAddressableSectors;
        public short SingleWordDMA;
        public short MultiWordDMA;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 382)]
        public byte[] Reserved2;
        public IDSECTOR()
        {
            VendorUnique = new short[3];
            Reserved2 = new byte[382];
            FirmwareRevision = new char[8];
            SerialNumber = new char[20];
            ModelNumber = new char[40];
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class SENDCMDOUTPARAMS
    {
        public int BufferSize;
        public DRIVERSTATUS Status;
        public IDSECTOR IDS;
        public SENDCMDOUTPARAMS()
        {
            Status = new DRIVERSTATUS();
            IDS = new IDSECTOR();
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int CloseHandle(int hObject);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int CreateFile(
                string lpFileName,
                uint dwDesiredAccess,
                int dwShareMode,
                int lpSecurityAttributes,
                int dwCreationDisposition,
                int dwFlagsAndAttributes,
                int hTemplateFile
            );

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int DeviceIoControl(
            int hDevice,
            int dwIoControlCode,
            [In(), Out()] SENDCMDINPARAMS lpInBuffer,
            int lpInBufferSize,
            [In(), Out()] SENDCMDOUTPARAMS lpOutBuffer,
            int lpOutBufferSize,
            ref int lpBytesReturned,
            int lpOverlapped
        );

    private string SwapChars(char[] chars)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= chars.Length - 2; i += 2)
        {
            char t;
            t = chars[i];
            chars[i] = chars[i + 1];
            chars[i + 1] = t;
        }
        string s = new string(chars);
        return s;
    }


     private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        string serialNumber = " ", model = " ", firmware = " ";
        bool result;
        DriveTypes driveType = DriveTypes.Unknown;
        int handle, returnSize = 0;
        int driveNumber = 0;
        SENDCMDINPARAMS sci = new SENDCMDINPARAMS();
        SENDCMDOUTPARAMS sco = new SENDCMDOUTPARAMS();

        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
            //               \\.\PhysicalDrive0    Opens the first physical drive.
            //               \\.\PhysicalDrive2    Opens the third physical drive.
            // see more info on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx
            handle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive" + "0", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
        else // for win'9x
            handle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\Smartvsd", 0, 0, 0, CREATE_NEW, 0, 0);
        if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            sci.DriveNumber = (byte)driveNumber;
            sci.BufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(sco);
            sci.DriveRegs.DriveHead = (byte)(0xA0 | driveNumber << 4);
            sci.DriveRegs.Command = 0xEC;
            sci.DriveRegs.SectorCount = 1;
            sci.DriveRegs.SectorNumber = 1;
            if (DeviceIoControl(handle, DFP_RECEIVE_DRIVE_DATA, sci, Marshal.SizeOf(sci), sco, Marshal.SizeOf(sco), ref returnSize, 0) != 0)
            {
                serialNumber = SwapChars(sco.IDS.SerialNumber);
                model = SwapChars(sco.IDS.ModelNumber);
                firmware = SwapChars(sco.IDS.FirmwareRevision);
            }

            textBox1.Text = serialNumber;
            textBox2.Text = model;
            textBox3.Text = firmware;
            if ((sco.IDS.GenConfig & 0x80) == 0x40)
                driveType = DriveTypes.Removable;
            else if ((sco.IDS.GenConfig & 0x40) == 0x40)
                driveType = DriveTypes.Fixed;
            else
                driveType = DriveTypes.Unknown;
            CloseHandle(handle);
            textBox4.Text = DriveStrings[(int)driveType];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A perfectly working solution can be found here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16941/Get-Physical-HDD-Serial-Number-without-WMI

[edit]
Sorry, missed that a reference to this has already been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the:

[GetVolumeInformation](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetVolumeInformation.html)

Win32 API function to get this information, if you must avoid WMI.  The linked page gives full the declaration signature (in both VB & C#) for the API function along with sample code.

Comment: Is it not returning the Volume serial number? I want the device serial number which does not change with formatting

Comment: @Xinxua - Sorry, you're correct.  It returns the volume rather than the device serial.  I think the only way to achieve this without using WMI is to call down into low-level OS functions called by C++/unmanaged code (as per the other Espo's answer), however, if you're running with limited Windows account privileges and WMI is failing (probably because of this) then I doubt that calling a C++ dll's functions from a .NET app will work either unless you can run/execute code as a higher privilege, and that would require the relevant access/passwords to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am using hdd firmware track in my projects. I programmed behind the mdi form to look for hdd firmware number, then its looping on all the provided numbers of hdds of companies computers and if it matches anyone amongst these provided hdds firmware numbers, then run the applicatoin and load mdi form other wise provides a message "The application is not registed on this machine, please call Mr. Afridi to register this application on 00923339176357. My email address is munawar_s_afridi@yahoo.com.  I will send complete source code of fetching how to programm professionaly hdd firmware number and how to stop others by using your app illegaly.

One lovely thing that you should specify all the company computers hdd firmware at once and let the application first pick the hdd firmware number, store it in a variable and then pick the value of this variable(a string value) and loop it one by one with each hdd number by using OR  logical operator. If it finds a matching number amongst the companies hdds numbers with variable value, then app should load main form(mdi) other wise notify the user for registration.

The sample code will be provided using vb6. You can easily programm later on in vb.net just by understanding how to call unmanaged code in to a managed .net application. In this case a .dll.

Answer (score 0):

Your best options is windows api,

i made a simple search and got this

[General processor info](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=processor&namespace=%5BAll%5D) and also [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582680/safest-way-to-get-processor-id-or-some-hardware-info)