# Is it possible to read serial number from a harddisk in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the Harddisk Device Serial Number without using the WMI in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176887/how-can-i-find-the-harddisk-device-serial-number-without-using-the-wmi-in-net)

how to read the serial number from a harddisk in c#? Any suggestion...

**EDIT:**

I want harddisk serial no and not for each partitions...