# Get the serial number of the hard disk of the client system

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using C#.net ,asp.net and .net framework 2.
How to get the serial number of the hard disk of the client system using javascript or asp.net ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot. You'll need client-side code with more access to the machine (A .NET application might be a good choice, based on your ASP.NET experience. Silverlight might also work; not sure).

Comment: You can't. This would be a security flaw if it would be possible. If you want to do it ouside your browser with a full application, please [read this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582680/safest-way-to-get-processor-id-or-some-hardware-info/4582698#4582698).

Comment: and clickonce can be a good option for simple setup on the client side

Comment: are u sure ? what is ur judgment about this http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_drive.asp ? Thanks

Comment: Jessica, that returns information about the *server-side* drive. Not the client.

Comment: @JessicaWatson This is VBScript, not JavaScript. In addition, it can be run ON THE SERVER-SIDE, at least what the examples in your link indicate.

Comment: is this possible to get the serial with WMI ?

Comment: Yes, if you're running code **on the client side with appropriate access**. Not JavaScript, and not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Get Client machine information by Asif Ali

```
var strComputer = ".";
var SWBemlocator = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
var objWMIService = SWBemlocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, "/root/CIMV2");
var strProcess;
var colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");

var e = new Enumerator(colItems);
for(; ! e.atEnd(); e.moveNext())
{
  strProcess += "itema "+ e.item().Name + "<br>\n";
}

colItems = 
      objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from    Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
      where IPEnabled=true");
e = new Enumerator(colItems);
for(; ! e.atEnd(); e.moveNext())
{
  strProcess += "itemb "+ e.item().Name + "<br>\n";
}

document.getElementById('sys_info').innerHTML = strProcess;
```